# How should I handl mixed tenses or tense agreements?

Tags: sentence-construction, backshifting, tense-agreement

> 1. Would it be okay if I called you when I **got** back home?
> 2. Would it be okay if I called you when I **get** back home?

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct? I'm still kind of confused about the tense agreement thing, and how backshifting works. What I don't get is: do I have to convert the entire sentence to the past, or do I have to convert certain parts of the sentence to the past?
Or whether I should keep a sentence where I have past tense strictly to the past.

Like:

> 1. I was walking down the street the other day, and it hit me how the world **worked**.
> 2. I was walking down the street the other day, and it hit me how the world **works**.

Do I keep the sentence in the past? Or do I mix the tenses?

Comment: In your first two examples, I think you might hear either one in informal conversation. For your second two examples, I think it depends on whether the world *still* works that way or not. This is just based on how it sounds to me as a native speaker so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I agree with @Era that either one is likely in informal speech.  "It hit me how the world worked" - that is, how the world worked at the time at the time I was walking down the street.  "It hit me how the world works" - that is, how the world works, in general, and presumably still does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth remembering that *morphologically*, English only has two tenses (present, and "not-present").

By *morphological* I mean that verbs themselves are only modified for tense by adding ***-ed*** to make "non-present" (there's ***ing*** to make "continuous", but that's an *aspect*, not a tense). For all other "tense" differences, we need auxiliary verbs (***be, have*** and things like ***will, would, should, could***).

Probably because of that, we're quite happy to use ***got*** in the first example (it's a hypothetical/future situation, where *got* actually implies "not-present" rather than "past"). In the second example, past tense ***worked*** simply echoes the past tense ***struck me***.

Note that present tense is also fine in both cases.

Comment: Every once in a while, you come across something like, "It's worth remembering that morphologically, English only has two tenses (present, and "not-present").", and it really makes you think. Good stuff FumbleFingers.